# Bluehost - wrong certificate presented by host for API call to Twilio

Tags: linux-networking, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

Bluehost VPS [running CentOS](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/vps-dedicated-change-os), but `cat /etc/redhat-release` reveals `CloudLinux release 6.10 (Final)`.

Executing curl commands against Twilio APIs on my local PC (Win11/IIS/PHP) works fine. When I attempt the same thing on my Bluehost server (with verbose output enabled), it fails with this message:

**certificate subject name '*.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'**

```
* About to connect() to api.twilio.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 50.19.189.95... connected
* Connected to api.twilio.com (50.19.189.95) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL: certificate subject name '*.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'
* NSS error -12276
* Closing connection #0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name '*.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'
```

Twilio support directed me to download their SSL cert through Chrome, which I did. I named the cert "cacert.pem", thinking that's what it needs to be named, but I have no idea. And here are the steps they had me perform in my bash terminal:

1. Upload the cacert.pem File: First, upload the cacert.pem file to your CentOS VPS. You can use secure file transfer methods like SCP or SFTP for this.
2. Determine the Certificate Store Location: The location of the certificate store may vary depending on the applications you want to use it with. For system-wide trust, you can typically place the certificate in /etc/pki/tls/certs/.
3. Copy the Certificate File: Copy the cacert.pem file to the certificate store:
   `sudo cp cacert.pem /etc/pki/tls/certs/`
4. Update the CA Certificate Bundle: To update the CA certificate bundle, run the following command:
   `sudo update-ca-trust enable`
5. Refresh the CA Trust: Update the CA trust using the update-ca-trust extract command:
   `sudo update-ca-trust extract`
6. Verify the Certificate Installation: You can verify that the certificate has been successfully installed by checking the CA bundle:
   `cat /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
   The `cacert.pem` content should be included in this bundle.
7. Restart Apache.

---

None of that made a difference and the wrong certificate is still presented.

I asked them "how does the OS know which certificate to use?" But they did not respond. Seems like that was never specified.

I ran a curl command (notice I use `-k` for insecure just to see what would happen) against Twilio API and got the following error:

> Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization
> header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires
> 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of
> either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=Basic
> QUNmN***

I ran the 2 following `dig` diagnostics on the Bluehost server:

```
dig api.twilio.com
```

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> api.twilio.com
> ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY,
> status: NOERROR, id: 58818 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9,
> AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;api.twilio.com.                        IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: api.twilio.com.         20      IN      CNAME
> virginia.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. virginia.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. 20 IN
> CNAME   self-healing.api-alb.us1.api-lb.twilio.com.
> self-healing.api-alb.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. 20 IN CNAME
> ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
> ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A
> 34.204.146.75 ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A 52.20.98.48 ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
> 20 IN A 35.153.214.247
> ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A
> 54.208.14.118 ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A 54.242.5.138
> ien-alb-bapi-b-156106065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A
> 34.232.251.189
>
> ;; Query time: 10 msec ;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) ;; WHEN: Fri Nov
> 3 08:51:38 2023 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 260

```
dig api.twilio.com @8.8.8.8
```

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> api.twilio.com
> @8.8.8.8 ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<-
> opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58143 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY:
> 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;api.twilio.com.                        IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: api.twilio.com.         21      IN      CNAME
> virginia.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. virginia.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. 21 IN
> CNAME   self-healing.api-alb.us1.api-lb.twilio.com.
> self-healing.api-alb.us1.api-lb.twilio.com. 21 IN CNAME
> ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
> ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A
> 3.222.47.158 ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A 34.236.63.82
> ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A
> 52.0.177.50 ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A 34.232.27.126
> ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A
> 3.225.164.19 ien-alb-bapi-a-1963256146.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 21 IN A 52.206.184.52
>
> ;; Query time: 23 msec ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) ;; WHEN: Fri Nov
> 3 08:52:11 2023 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 261

I tried the following on NOV-4 based on Turdie's suggestion:

```
curl -v --tlsv1.2 -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACf7b58ec793***4d/Messages.json" \
> --data-urlencode "Body=This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?" \
> --data-urlencode "From=+14*****40" \
> --data-urlencode "To=+18*****44" \
> -u ACf7b*****30a4d:0ce7445d*****48bc4d
```

RESULT:

> - About to connect() to api.twilio.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 50.19.189.95... Timeout
> - Trying 35.168.202.10... Timeout
> - Trying 54.173.225.186... Timeout
> - Trying 107.22.7.7... Timeout
> - Trying 52.204.229.116... connected
> - Connected to api.twilio.com (52.204.229.116) port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
> - SSL: certificate subject name '*.glympse.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'
> - NSS error -12276
> - Closing connection #0 curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name '*.glympse.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'

I also tried the following on NOV-4 based on Turdie's suggestion:

```
openssl s_client -connect api.twilio.com
```

RESULT:

> no port defined

(After that it spit out a ton of available args, like documentation. Not sure if you wanted that.)

I am a developer, but a novice with linux and certs, so I'm hoping someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blog.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux-os-6-has-officially-reached-its-end-of-life ***” CloudLinux OS 6 has officially reached its End-Of-Life on November 30, 2020”*** - Note with legacy software you might run into the issue that it does not implement SNI and you therefore don’t get the correct TLS certificate when you connect to a host that relies on [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to present you the correct certificates (and the steps you took are irrelevant to address that)

Comment: You might want to check and see what happens when you use the `curl -k` insecure option to skip the validity check of the certificate

Comment: Those Twilio people are clearly insane; your problem has nothiing to do with the cert not validating against the truststore and no change to the truststore is needed, and if it were their method is almost entirely wrong. **Your actual problem is that you aren't connecting to api.twilio.com at all.** 50.19.189.95 is not an address for that domain -- see https://dnschecker.org/#A/api.twilio.com -- and it actually connects to some **different and wrong host**, albeit also in amazon us-east-1. Check the name resolution being used on your server, probably but not necessarily DNS.

Comment: @HBruijn: in general possibly, but in this case the [real api.twilio.com hosts](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.twilio.com) give the same cert with or without SNI and and 50.19.189.95 gives a _different_ cert but also the same with or without SNI -- and the cert from 50.19.189.95 isn't for twilio because 50.19.189.95 is not twilio at all.

Comment: HBruijn, I tried `curl -k` and edited my original post with those results.

Comment: When, as the comments from @dave_thompson_085 suggest, you're connecting to the wrong host, that is what you need to investigate and possibly correct first. Because you're never going to get a correct result when your application is connecting to the wrong host/API That might be caused by a stale DNS record or an override coded in your systems `/etc/hosts` file or maybe something else.

Comment: HBruijn, I just examined my /etc/hosts file - only a few lines as expected, no mention of twilio or the IP `50.19.189.95`. When I ping api.twilio.com I see the IP is  `34.204.146.75`.  Do you think I should add the following line to my hosts file:  `34.204.146.75 api.twilio.com` ?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder run these command on your server and share the output: `dig api.twilio.com` and `dig api.twilio.com @8.8.8.8`. If they don't give a fairly similar response it suggests that your DNS server is redirecting the traffic, or has some kind of misconfiguration.

Comment: Trevelyan: Thank you. I posted the results of the `dig` diagnostics in my original post, but I don't know how to interpret the results. What do you think?

Comment: Obviously the external/public hosts are hitting a completely different set of IP addresses than your Blue host. Different paths and data flows. This isn't unusual today, as many vendors have there entire infrastructure in AWS which adds complexity. We also don't know where the external host is in relation to the Bluehost target so that diminishes the value of the data. The addresses received may be determined by region.

Comment: Worth noting that all of the IP addresses returned from the dig command run on the Bluehost, and the original IP address, all present the correct Twilio certificate when queried by VirusTotal.

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect api.twilio.com` say? If you are presented with an aws certificate your probably getting redirected to a endpoint which uses a local server certificate.

Comment: Check this https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.twilio.com&latest. When I test using ssllabs im getting a *.twilio.com cert

Comment: What i find strange is this `Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb`

Comment: Turdie, I tried both your suggestions and posted the results in my original question.

Comment: @Turdie: yes ssllabs finds good certs, as I posted days ago; now look at the _addresses_ ssllabs used and you'll see they are all different from the address Herriman's curl is using -- it isn't connecting to api.twilio.com in the first place. (Also the `Initializing NSS` message is perfectly normal for builds of curl using NSS.) Herriman: try `getent hosts api.twilio.com` and `getent ahostsv4 api.twilio.com | grep STREAM`. Also I note dnschecker now shows 6 different addresses from some areas -- but still all different from Herriman's curl.

Comment: @GregAskew: AWS isn't a CDN (except for cloudfront, which this isn't). Look at my dnschecker link and this domain now resolves to two sets of 6 addresses -- possibly a VM instance restart? -- but the same two sets all over the world, and neither of them containing any of the addresses Herriman is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research this is an issue with curl.

You need to use
`curl -v --tlsv1.2`

This looks like a similar issue as the TS is experiencing

https://blog.michaelfmcnamara.com/2015/12/curl-and-ssl-tls-issues/

It seems like in your curl, you are sending a certificate with the glympse.com NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb. That causes a mismatch because twilio.com and glympse is a different name.
I think you need to check with twilio.com which certificate you need to use to connect to the api. It also looks like your are using nssdb and a sql database, i dont have any knowledge of that.

The last line in the curl clearly states the certificate mismatch
`Closing connection #0 curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name '*.glympse.com' does not match target host name 'api.twilio.com'`

Edit

Where is your api key in this? Check the docs

```
curl -v --tlsv1.2 -X POST "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACf7b58ec793***4d/Messages.json" \
> --data-urlencode "Body=This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?" \
> --data-urlencode "From=+14*****40" \
> --data-urlencode "To=+18*****44" \
> -u ACf7b*****30a4d:0ce7445d****
```

Comment: Turdie, thank you. What you suggested didn't fully work, but this seems MUCH CLOSER than I have ever gotten before. No SMS was sent, but the results are promising. I posted the entire results up on my original post. Any ideas how I can take this across the finish line?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the port, it should be `openssl s_client -connect api.twilio.com:443`. For the rest see the edits.

Comment: I tried your latest with the port and it just prompts me with a cursor. No idea what to enter now, and I don't know what you mean by `For the rest see the edits`.

Comment: Try this in curl : To ignore invalid and self-signed certificate checks on Curl, use the -k or --insecure command-line option

Comment: The `-k`- didn't make any difference, though the result messages were a little different.

Comment: You are somehow sending a wrong certificate which causes the certificate mismatch, look into the nss what that does, it's probably coming from there. And I don't see an api key in your request which is stated in the docs

Comment: Turdie, there are 2 API keys, both in the last line, as shown. That curl works fine on my local machine running PHP on IIS and the SMS gets sent. It just doesn't work on Bluehost. And also I don't know what you mean by "look into the nss what that does".

Comment: If you mean client cert aka client auth, OP isn't sending any cert at all, and neither the real api.twilio.com hosts nor the host OP is connecting to requests a client cert so it isn't even possible to send one. (Twilio does want an the API key but that's not a cert and not in the TLS handshake anywhere.)

Comment: Dave, any ideas on a solution for this?